# What Python sklearn function can take non-numeric values as training target?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am learning the [example](https://data-flair.training/blogs/advanced-python-project-detecting-fake-news/).

I noticed that they used PassiveAggressiveClassifier that can take non-numeric y_train values. I understand in Natural Language Processing (NLP) we need to convert string training text to numeric arrays as training input so that neural network models can take it, but why training target does not need to be converted to numeric? What other models can take non-numeric training target?

```
#Initialize a PassiveAggressiveClassifier
pac=PassiveAggressiveClassifier(max_iter=50)
pac.fit(tfidf_train,y_train)
```

Comment: You don't need to calculate distances between labels or use their coordinates as you do with features

Comment: Non-numeric targets are like categories which for ease of understanding may not require to convert to numeric values. Also, as Hellpanderr said, no calculation is required over these values.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 different things here:
- when you are doing a **classification** task, the names of your categories do not matter since there is no notion of distance between them. For example, if you are doing a logistic regression, you can label the positive answers as 'yes', 'positive' or '1', and the negative ones as 'no', 'negative', or '0'. That will have absolutely no impact on how your models train.
- when you are training an NLP model, you want to define some distance on the words of your vocabulary. For example, you want to know that 'car' is similar to 'bus', but that 'car' is not similar to 'apple'. The best way to do it is to represent them as vectors that will be more or less distant from one another according to their semantic meaning (we are using here the euclidean distance on vectors). That's why we give this representation of words to NLP models: you want your models to understand that 'car' and 'bus' are close, which is not possible if you keep them as words.

Note: any classification task can take words as labels.

See https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5021-distributed-representations-of-words-and-phrases-and-their-compositionality.pdf for more details concerning vector representation of words (i.e. word embedding).